# Использование данных с сервера напрямую или создание объектов своего класса?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

У меня есть приложение на angular, в котором есть страница новостей. Список новостей(массив) я получаю с api сервера. Я могу использовать полученные данные напрямую, но может лучше создать класс NewsItem, который полностью повторяет структуру каждой новости из массива и получаемые данные преобразовывать в массив объектов NewsItem[]?

**Пример кода без преобразовывания:**

В *news.service.ts*

```
getNews(leftBound:number, rightBound:number) {
    return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + `/api/news/${leftBound}/${rightBound}`)
}
```

В *news.component.ts*

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.newsService.getNews(this.leftBound, this.rightBound).subscribe( 
        (response) => {
            this.news = response.json();
        })
}
```

**Пример кода c преобразовыванием:**

В *news.service.ts*

```
getNews(leftBound:number, rightBound:number):Observable<NewsItem[]> {
    return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + `/api/news/${leftBound}/${rightBound}`)
                .map((resp:Response) => {
                    let newsList = resp.json();
                    let news: NewsItem[] = [];
                    for(let i in newsList){
                      let item = newsList[i];
                      news.push(new NewsItem(item.title, item.date, item.text));
                    }
                    return news;
                })
}
```

В *news.component.ts*

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.newsService.getNews(this.leftBound, this.rightBound).subscribe( (news) => {
        this.news = news;
    })
}
```

Класс *NewsItem*

```
@Injectable()
export class NewsItem{
  date: string;
  title: string;
  text: string;
  constructor(title: string, date: string, text: string){
    this.title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```

Далее, в обоих случаях одинаково, я вывожу новости в шаблоне компонента.

Как лучше сделать в данной ситуации?
И в целом, всегда ли нужно создавать свои классы или же бывают случаи, когда лучше не усложнять себе задачу и просто воспользоваться данными, полученными с сервера?

Comment: приведи пример кода про _преобразовывание_ и _использование сразу_

Comment: @Grundy пример добавил. Мне скорее не понятно, нужно ли создавать свои классы, если можно сразу работать с данными, которые я получил с сервера? При этом наличия методов не предполагается.

Comment: добавь определение класса _NewsItem_

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript добавляет возможность использовать типы в определениях переменных и функций, а также возможность проверить эти типы в момент компиляции. Это может помочь избежать некоторых ошибок связанных с передачей неожиданных объектов.

Если точно известно, что должна возвращать функция, то лучше указать тип возвращаемого значения.

В данном случае, всегда ожидается `Observable<NewsItem[]>`, поэтому вполне нормально указать именно его.

С другой стороны, так как класс *NewsItem* представляет из себя лишь данные, по крайней мере в данном примере, то нет нужды использовать приведение. Можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что *resp.json()* возвращает объект типа `any`, а такие объекты можно присвоить *любому* типу.

В итоге код функции может быть следующим:

```
getNews(leftBound:number, rightBound:number) {
    return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + `/api/news/${leftBound}/${rightBound}`)
               .map((resp:Response) => {
                   let newsList = resp.json();
                   return newsList;
               }
}
```

И в самой подписке останется простое присвоение, так как тело json уже было взято

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.newsService.getNews(this.leftBound, this.rightBound).subscribe( (news) => {
        this.news = news;
    })
}
```

В итоге: нет лишнего цикла, есть типизированный результат.

> Мне скорее не понятно, нужно ли создавать свои классы, если можно сразу работать с данными, которые я получил с сервера?

*свои классы* позволят использовать мощь проверки типов, что в свою очередь  поможет избежать некоторых видов ошибок, а так же добавляет подсказки по используемым полям.

С другой стороны, есть тип *any*, в который можно записать *любое* значение. Но при его использовании теряется подсказка доступных полей, а так же добавляется шанс передать в функцию значение определенного класса.

Итого: если данные никак не используются в коде, а только выводятся во view, большой разницы между типизированным значением и any не будет. Если же с данными планируются еще какие-то операции - то лучше указывать тип, и, соответственно, создавать свои классы (либо interface)

Comment: Большое спасибо. В дополнение хочу спросить, при работе на javascript, где нет строгой типизации, создание класса так-же не имеет смысла, если данные только выводятся во view?

Comment: @КолькаТесемин, если ты этими данными нигде не пользуешься, а просто сразу выводишь во view, то да - класс не нужен. Он не даст никаких преимуществ. Максимум его можно использовать как задел на будущее, когда возможно ты захочешь как-то обработать данные перед выводом